# Is it possible to download [ETA 539-Weekly Claims and Extended Benefits Trigger Data] through the DOL API?

Tags: labor

is it possible to download the DOL's ETA 539 weekly report through the DOL API?

[ETA 539 Report information can be found here... scroll down to report.](https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/DataDownloads.asp)

[ETA 539 raw data.](https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/csv/ar539.csv)

[DOL Developer tools link.](https://developer.dol.gov)